# Error: "scipy.misc module has no attribute imread" in Anaconda Jupyter

Tags: scipy, anaconda, jupyter

When trying to use the line >> `photo_data = misc.imread('./wifire/sd-3layers.jpg')`, I receive the error output above.

I did everything as in the instruction video before running it, i.e.

```
%matplotlib inline; 
import numpy as np;
from scipy import misc;
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage import data
```

The folder is in the correct working directory (user 2), so the isssue seems to lie in the imread function missing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The [docu](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.2.1/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imread.html) says:

> `imread is deprecated! imread is deprecated in SciPy 1.0.0, and will
>   be removed in 1.2.0. Use imageio.imread instead.`

[`imageio.imread()`](https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/userapi.html#imageio.imread)